# MySQL update enums

Tags: php, mysql, sql, enums, sql-update

I have a field with enums: 'preview','active','closed'

When I query like this:

```
        $query = "UPDATE albums 
                SET album_active = preview 
                WHERE album_id = 3";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
```

I get:

`Invalid query: Unknown column 'preview' in 'field list`

Other query:

```
        $query = sprintf("UPDATE albums SET 
                    album_active = %s 
                    WHERE album_id = %d", 
                    $_POST['album_active'], 
                    $_POST['album_id']
            );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `preview` in quotes as:

```
SET album_active = 'preview'
```

Without the quotes `preview` will be recognized by the query parser as a column name, something like:

```
UPDATE TABLE T
SET column1 = column2
WHERE...
```

Comment: that works, actually I have a query with sprintf(). See updated code. cheers.

Comment: cool! another question.. are all datatypes sended by $_POST converted to strings?